# jsoup getElementsByAttribute Issue

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

here input code

```
<table style=”padding: 0px; margin: 0px;” cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="626" align="center" bgcolor="White" border="0">
<tr>
<td style=”vertical-align: top;” height="61" valign="top" bgcolor="#0492CB"><a href="http://www.aoec.com"> <img alt="AoEC" src="http://www.aoec.com/email/mute/images/header.gif" style="width: 626px; height: 61px;" border="0" /></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

java coding is

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(code);
Elements elements = doc.getElementsByAttribute("style");
for(int se=0;se<elements.size();se++)
{
 System.out.println(elements.get(se).attr("style"));
}
```

out-put is

```
padding:;
vertical-align:;
```

In above code getElementsByAttribute("style") is not working..

Answer (score 2):

The curly quotes `”` are not valid attribute separators. You need straight quotes instead: `"` or `'`.

Your code is fine. The input HTML is just invalid. This has to be reported to the original HTML author so that s/he can fix the HTML (it would namely also break in a normal webbrowser).

If this HTML is outside your control, consider using `String#replace()` to replace the invalid quotes.

```
code = code.replace('”', '"');
```

Or, if the character encodings in your environment are not already properly configured to UTF-8.

```
code = code.replace('\u201D', '"')
```

Comment: i handle this type of quotation i try to remove ” using ASCII value but at time problem;

Comment: code = code.replace('”', '"'); is not working in web-app that replaces   ? for that character

Comment: Apparently your code is not properly saved using UTF-8. Use `code = code.replace('\U201D', '"')` instead. I strongly recommend to revise the character encodings used in your environments anyway. By the way the term "ASCII 148" makes no sense. Do you have any idea or a slight understanding what you're talking about and what's going on here?

Comment: that's invalid escape sequence In eclipse Editor

Comment: Sorry, lowercase `u`, thus so `code = code.replace('\u201D', '"')`

Comment: that's also not working. that replaces ? Now I am use ASCII value. because of i have no experience  in character encoding environments Thanks for quick reply

Comment: That's scary. I'd really consult a manager/architect and have your environments reviewed. This is open for many more future problems.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is deprecated already. You should use `.select();` method. Also, it is a good idea to use foreach or iterator while looping through it, as a simple for may throw some NullPointerExceptions

You can find it's documentation [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

But as of not I'd use that:

```
//That should get you all tags that have the style attribute
Elements elements = doc.select("[style]");

//That foreach should avoid exceptions, and loop through the collection 
for(Element element : elements) {
    //The print gets a little cleaner too!
    System.out.println(element.attr("style"));
}
```

Comment: I know that but in that case use another double quotation so problem is created. my question is that how to handle this quotation.

Comment: If you have a tag stile="something="" something=""", it'll all come as you use what I just purposed